# VLookup for Cross Reference Document

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet with cross references, it has document numbers in the rows and columns and when a document references another I put a little X in the cell that corresponds to both.

[image]

What I want to do is create a Lookup function where someone inputs a document number and it searches along the row of that document number and wherever there is an X reads off what the document number is for that column (which would be in row 1) then it returns all the document numbers referenced.

I'm completely new to Excel/VBA and was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: See [Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data](http://tinyurl.com/kdxb7le).

Comment: @Jeeped It's just a visual to accompany trying to explain what my Excel doc looks like, not really essential to the question though.

Comment: Have you made an attempt to write any code? You'll have a better chance of getting an answer if you make an attempt to write the function yourself and then post back when you encounter a problem/error. [See this (especially the first paragraph and list).](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for my messy script, but this might be what you're after.

```
Function RefDocs(r As Range, c As Range, x As Range) As String
'   Generates a list of references for X

'   Variables
'   r - range for the vertical IDs (e.g. A2:A16)
'   c - range for horizontal IDs (e.g. B1:P1
'   x - the cell you've got the document ID you're cross referencing

    Dim lOffset As Long
    Dim rg As Range, rFind As Range

        Set rFind = r.Find(What:=x.Value)

        If rFind Is Nothing Then Exit Function

        lOffset = rFind.Row - c.Row

        With r.Parent
            For Each rg In c
                If rg.Offset(lOffset, 0).Value = "X" Then
                    RefDocs = RefDocs & .Cells(c.Row, rg.Column).Value & "; "
                End If
            Next rg
        End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The formula:
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("X",INDIRECT("B"&MATCH(O9,$A$2:$A$21)+1&":M"&MATCH(O9,$A$2:$A$21)+1))+1)) seems like it might work

Cell O9 is the input cell where you type the value you're looking up in the table. That value is looked up in cell range: A2:A21, then the function looks for an X in that row. It returns the value in row 1 of that column.

In this example the table with X's is B2:M21, which is handled by the nested Indirect function.

Comment: Thanks for this. It works, however; do you know if it's possible to return a list so if a row has more than one X in it? Thanks

Comment: Probably not possible to make this formula handle multiple matches in a row. In that case, I would use the VBA approach.